# auto-complete and emacs c++ mode

Tags: c++, emacs

I try to use auto-complete for coding in c++. But he doesn't work in c++, when i'm starting to write something like "namespace" or "while" it propose nothing unlike in Lisp when i edit my init.el.

init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/arthur/.emacs.d/auto-complete/")
(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "/home/arthur/.emacs.d/auto-complete/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

How can i fix my problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet), this video([Emacs as a C/C++ Editor/IDE (Part I): auto-complete, yasnipp ...](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTUE03LnaXA)) will help you.